# Why is $ \frac{1}{4\pi} \int \int_S dx \, dy\, \vec{n} \cdot ( \partial_x \vec{n} \times \partial_y \vec{n} ) = 1 $?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-fields, k-theory

I am trying to understand this notion of "topological charge" from a paper in Physics Review Letters.  They talk about [skyrmions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_skyrmion) and give this integral (here $\vec{n}$ is a vector field on the sphere, from unit vectors in 3-space, which is also a sphere.) :
$$ \frac{1}{4\pi} \int \int_S dx \, dy\, \Big[ \vec{n} \cdot ( \partial_x \vec{n} \times \partial_y \vec{n} ) \Big]  = 1  \in \mathbb{Z}$$
In this case, this is reduced to a vector calculus problem, there's lots of questions that this result was a whole number.  The [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) discusses this notion for a curve in the plane winding around a point or since this an integral over $S^2$ we can talk about "degree".  One other possible statement is:
$$ \pi_3(S^3) = \mathbb{Z} $$
which is relatd to the [Hopf fibration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#%CF%803(S2)_=_%E2%84%A4).  In this case, there's no more integral.  Discussions of [K-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-theory) are very technical, there's is also article on [vector bundles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle).

Comment: Your Hopf fibration comment is, incidentally, giving you $\pi_3(S^2)$, not $\pi_3(S^3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is a bit vague and the physicists are being sloppy, as usual. $\vec n$ is simultaneously the position vector on the unit sphere and the unit outward normal field. You cannot parametrize the entire sphere by $(x,y)$, but what the integrand is supposed to represent (if you *had* a surface that could be parametrized by a region in the $xy$-plane) is the surface area element of the sphere, pulled back by the $(x,y)$-parametrization. Taking all these grains of salt into account, the integral is *supposed* to represent the surface area of the entire sphere, which, of course, is $4\pi$.

In general, if $\mathbf x(u,v)$ is parametrizing a surface $S\subset\Bbb R^3$ as $(u,v)$ varies in a region $D$ in the $uv$-plane, then for a vector field $\vec F$ on $S$, the integral
$$\int_D \vec F(\mathbf x(u,v))\cdot \big(\frac{\partial\mathbf x}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf x}{\partial v}\big)du\,dv$$
gives the flux of $\vec F$ across $S$. The flux of the position vector on the unit sphere gives the surface area of the sphere.